A contradiction about an open set whose boundary is not of measure zero.
We construct a bounded open set $A$ in $\mathbf{R}$ such that $BdA$ does not have measure zero. The rational numbers in the open interval $(0,1)$ are countable; let us arrange them in sequence $q_{1},q_{2},\cdots$. Let $0<a<1$ be fixed. For each $i$, choose an open interval $(a_{i},b_{i})$ of length less than $\frac{a}{2^{i}}$ that contains $q_{i}$ and contained in $(0,1)$. Let $A$ be the following open set of $\mathbf{R}$:
$$A=(a_{1},b_{1})\cup(a_{2},b_{2})\cup\cdots=I_{1}\cup I_{2}\cup\cdots$$
In Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, page 113 Example 1, he proves $BdA$ is not of measure zero. I can understand his proof, but I meet some difficulties when I think this problem in another way.
We know that $BdI_{k}=\{a_{k},b_{k}\}$ is of measure zero (in $\mathbf{R}$). So, $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}BdI_{k}$ is of measure zero.
Since $Bd(a_{1},b_{1})\cup(a_{2},b_{2})\cup\cdots\cup(a_{n},b_{n})\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}BdI_{k}$, we have $BdA\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}BdI_{k}$. As a result, we have $BdA$ is of measure zero. But, in fact, $BdA$ is not of measure zero. Where do I go wrong?

The boundary of $A$ is not contained in the union of boundaries of all intervals.

@DavidGao How can I understand it "intuitively" ?

@AnneBauval No, they are two different questions.

I know they are different, but it answers precisely your question "Where do I go wrong" (expanding @DavidGao's comment).

@studyhard It might be better to think about closures instead of boundaries. The closure of a set contains limits of sequences of elements of that set. If it’s a finite union, then any sequence has a subsequence contained in one of the subsets, so the closure of the union is contained in the union of closures. If it is an infinite union, the above needs not be true - there can be plenty of sequences which only contain one point from each of the subsets, say. To put it another way, there can be points that can only be approximated by points in different subsets, but never any fixed one of them.

...and the two answers in the linked post illustrate it perfectly.

@DavidGao Thank you. It's a good explanation.

@AnneBauval Thank you!

An explicit example of David's first comment is that the countable union of all rational numbers has boundary $\mathbb{R}$, but the set consisting of a single rational number $x$ has boundary equal to that 1-element set ${x}$. So the union of boundary points of rationals is not the same as the boundary of the union. $Bd(\cup_{x \in \mathbb{Q}} {x}) = \mathbb{R}, \cup_{x \in \mathbb{Q}} Bd({x})=\mathbb{Q}$.
